# Searching index of a range of values in an array using python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, tuples

I am using the following code to find  the indices

```
result1=np.where(np.logical_and(R[i,:]>= 30, R[i,:]<= 30.3))
```

The output is

```
result1 = (array([284, 285]),)
```

When I run `len(result1)` I get a value of one.
Why is the length one when there are 2 elements.
The two numbers are indexes. I need to use the indexes but cannot because `len(result1)` is one.
I tried changing it to list but that did not help.
Please help me with this.

Comment: Try `len(result1[0])`. Then you should get `2`.

Comment: `where` returns a tuple. You want to use `len(result1[0])`.

Comment: The `(... ,)` aren't just decorations.  They tell us something about the object.

Answer (score 0):

`result1` is a tuple containing a *single array*, and thus has a length of 1; it is the *array* that has 2 elements.

Comment: Hi Guys,
Thanks a lot. I have one more question. 
When I type "result". I get the following
   array([[199., 200.],
          [199., 200.],
          [199., 200.],
          [199., 200.],
          [199., 200.],
          [199., 200.],
          [199., 200.],

The numbers 199 and 200 are indices. I would like to use the indices such as 
      `z[0,result[0,0]] 
or    `z[0,result[0,1]]`
or    `z[1,result[0,0]]`
I have not been able to figure that out.
Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like len(result1[0]) or if you can remember later use like this; result1 = ([284,285],'') ->  len(result1).